# Efficiently determine intersection size for all combinations of sets and assign it to combination of set names

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations, python-itertools, intersection

I am loading multiple csv files into pandas DataFrames which I then again store in a single list. All DataFrames have the same number of columns (containing strings) and equal headers. I now want to find the intersection size of a certain column for all combinations of the DataFrames. So for n DataFrames (or columns), I should have 2<sup>n</sup>-n-1 values in the end.
From a list of names referring to each DataFrame, I also want to get the combinations of these names which are then assigned to each corresponding intersection size value.

My code is already working, however, I feel it can be improved since I currently convert object types multiple times. Here is an example with `lst` containing above-mentioned names and `lst_data` containing nested lists to substitute for the actual csv file I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as itt

lst = ['A','B','C','D']
lst_data = [['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'], ['B1','A2', 'B3', 'B4'], ['C1', 'C2', 'A3', 'B4'], ['D1', 'A2', 'B3', 'C4']]

dct = {}
for letter in range(len(lst)):  
  dct.update({lst[letter]:set(pd.Series(lst_data[letter]))})

dct_combi = []
for comb in range(2, len(lst)+1):
    dct_combi.append(list(map(dict, itt.combinations(dct.items(), comb))))
        
intsxn = {}
for i in range(len(dct_combi)):
    for k in range(len(dct_combi[i])):
        intsxn.update(
            {'_'.join(dct_combi[i][k].keys()):len(set.intersection(*(list(dct_combi[i][k].values()))))}
            )
```

I have to work with very large datasets and I am not sure if all this type conversion might decrease performance. I definitely need something like the `intsxn` dictionary above: the different combinations of names (which refer to a Series in a DataFrame imported from a csv) assigned to the corresponding intersection size.

Is there a more efficient/elegant way to achieve the same?